# For what classes of ODE can one conclude that "an ordinary differential equation of the $n$th order has an $n$-parameter family of solutions"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

"*An ordinary differential equation of the $n$th order has an $n$-parameter family of solutions*" is a false statement because we can find counterexamples:

- $(y'-y)(y'-2y)=0$ has the solution which has two arbitrary constants instead one.
- $(y')^2+y^2=0$ has the solution which has zero arbitrary constants instead of one.

However, sometimes people say for "most" ordinary differential equations, the statement "*an ordinary differential equation of the $n$th order has an $n$-parameter family of solutions*" is true. So my question is, for what class of ordinary differential equations is the statement "*an ordinary differential equation of the $n$th order has an $n$-parameter family of solutions*" true?

Comment: It depends on how you define "ordinary". Sometimes it includes "explicit" so that then both examples are excluded.

Comment: @LutzLehmann, I thought "ordinary differential equation" is a very mature subject and surely there is a universally accepted definition of ode. Am I having a misunderstanding of anything?

Comment: Your statement is not true because it requires additional conditions such as uniqueness, that is, a Lipschitz condition. Your equations are implicit DE that are usually not considered "ordinary" as that class also includes DAE and systems that are not even DAE (in that they have no locally constant index).

Comment: Or said another way, "ordinary differential equation" is a topic, not a class of differential equations. This topic historically includes subjects such as Clairauts DE that have clever solution procedures, but would more correctly be classed as DAE or ODE on manifolds. The usually next subject is existence-and-uniqueness theory, where my bias towards what ODE are comes from, and also the claim in question. The main practical subject is of course systems of linear DE, esp. those with constant coefficients. The topic is rounded up with Sturm-Liouville theory of BVP and special functions.